# matplotlib 64 bit bar blank

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using newest version of 64 bit Python officially released by [Python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) on Windows 10.

```
>>> sys.version
'2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
```

There are two data vectors `sp1` and `sp2` and are normalized to the highest value with highest value being 100. I want to `bar` in the same figure for comparison using `matplotlib`. However, the saved figure is white (or blank), as shown below. [image]
The codes I used for baring are:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import floor, ceil

sp1 = [[110.0709, 45.0], [113.105, 89.0], [114.1093, 236.0], [115.1071, 70.0], [116.1098, 332.036], [117.1118, 135.0], [118.1093, 276.0], [119.1148, 88.0], [120.0791, 49.0], [121.1197, 437.0], [136.0767, 34.1259], [139.0833, 36.0004], [141.0944, 58.036], [143.0981, 83.7717], [145.1055, 53.0], [147.1081, 42.0], [149.1147, 45.0], [158.0878, 49.0], [161.1083, 29.0], [175.1172, 188.5742]]
sp2 = [[101.0693, 51.0], [102.055, 35.0], [110.0711, 43.0], [112.0854, 47.0], [113.1062, 186.0], [114.1097, 501.0], [115.1083, 168.0], [116.1096, 829.0], [117.1132, 258.0], [118.1094, 614.0], [119.1123, 190.0], [120.1185, 36.0], [121.1199, 1049.0], [136.0735, 292.0], [139.0847, 107.0], [141.0918, 128.0], [143.1005, 232.0], [145.1077, 123.0], [147.1073, 112.0], [149.1159, 86.0]]
# x and y values of vector sp1
mz1, int1 = [x[0] for x in sp1], [x[1] for x in sp1]
# normalize the vector to the highest value with highest value being 100.
int1 = [x/max(int1)*100. for x in int1]
# x and y values of vector sp2
mz2, int2 = [x[0] for x in sp2], [x[1] for x in sp2]
# normalize the vector to the highest value with highest value being 100.
int2 = [x/max(int2)*-100. for x in int2]
# bar vectors
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
specbar1 = ax.bar(mz1, int1, width = 0.001)
specbar2 = ax.bar(mz2, int2, width = 0.001, color = 'r', edgecolor = 'r')
# plot baseline at y=0
xlim = ax.get_xlim()
xl = [x/10. for x in xrange(int(floor(xlim[0]))*10, int(ceil(xlim[1]))*10)]
yl = [0]*len(xl)
ax.plot(xl, yl, color = 'k')
# save figure
plt.savefig('test.png')
plt.close()
```

The codes are initially run in Python 32 bit, and went very well. Due to large scale of data I must process, I moved to Python 64 bit, then this `bar` problem occurs. However, the `plot` works, as shown above. How can I figure this?

Comment: Please read [mcve]. You  need to provide a reproducible example; how else should anybody here be able to understand the issue?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest part of data I used are provided and the figure enclosed are `bar` using this part of data.

Comment: The figure is not blank. It shows some of the bars. Can you comment on what you expect `width = 0.001` to do? if the plot is ~180 units wide on ~600 pixels, you have roughly 3 pixels per unit. So chances you see a bar of width 0.001 are 3 per mille.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I want each stick as thin as possible and is separable when the figure is zoomed since there exist very close values along `x axis` in my data. I re-implemented the codes with parameter `width=0.001` removed, several data points are still lost.

Comment: No, there is no data lost. If you remove `width=0.001` you will get the expected plot with 20 bars. See [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5PXJ.png)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest How about [this data](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jx2jpjiNlQGPXZyesmMfm43K0E7zCy__cbP94nqNPbA/edit?usp=sharing)?

Comment: The data is not lost, it is simply not shown. If you want to show a single line instead of a bar, use `plt.stem` instead of `plt.bar`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That's great, thanks! But I wonder why this happens?

Comment: In the data you have, you distribute 1 unit wide bars over ~1000 units. Showing that on a ~600 pixels wide graph, you still have the chance of only 60% to see a bar. You would need to make sure that the bar width is large enough to at least show on one pixel. Else it may not be drawn.